# Pass by Value and Pass by Reference in Android Adapter?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am passing ArrayList from Activity to RecyclerView adapter. But changing value in activity changing value in adapter too. how can i avoid this ?

```
List<Object> objectList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Object>());

        public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context,List<Object> commentDatas) {
            mContext = context;
            commentDataList = commentDatas;
}
```

Comment: Instead of passing the `ArrayList` create a copy of it and pass over the copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you didn't show your code, so I will show my code with example

When you create Adapter, you send data to Adapter via Adapter's contructor like this:

```
List<MyObject> list;

public RcvAdapter(List<MyObject> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }
```

If you want to solve your question, do this:

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public RcvAdapter(List<MyObject> list, Context context) {
            this.list.addAll(list);
            this.context = context;
        }
```

Hope this help!

Comment: why we adding this. ?

Comment: To make it become another list and not a reference of list in Activity. So If you change data on Activity list, it won't affect Adapter's list.